# Create tables in Powerdesigner PDM with SQL query

Tags: powerdesigner

Is it somehow possible to create tables in a pdm in powerdesigner with a SQL query? Since I already have all my  tables in SQL I would like to do some reverse engineering to create all the tables in the pdm based on create tables queries. Table name, columns and data type would be good enough to save a lot of manual work.

BR
Ted

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "with a SQL query". Do you mean "from the SQL creation script"? That would be `Database > Update Model from Database`, with the option `Using script file`.

Comment: wow, that is exactly what I meant. I just tried it and it worked as desired. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm able to create the tables and indexes with this solution. However the triggers seems to be a bit tricky, since I'm using trigger templates in powerdesigner. 

If I create the triggers via script file now, providing the source code for the body, the template items will not be added. So maybe there is a way to state which template items to add as well?

Comment: I don't know... PowerDesigner trigger templates provide an alternative implementation of integrity (instead of using foreign keys), plus some constraint checks (if I remember). Actual triggers may perform so much more, e.g. implementing complicated business rules, or cascades. I don't think this would translate to generic trigger items. But were your SQL scripts generated with PowerDesigner in the first place?

Comment: In this case they were not generated from PowerDesigner. But I do use PowerDesigner to generate new SQL scripts in a later phase and in those scripts I get the source code of each trigger, but they are generated based on the trigger templates and based on the reference and integrity between the tables. So I can't really use the source code of for example a delete trigger since it doesn't look the same for all tables. 

Anyhow, I'm more than satisfied for the help you already given me, it saves me a lot of manual work.